# how to creating dynamic view in android

Tags: android

In my application i am going to create everything dynamic  based on the some server responce so now I have created on LinearLayout  which contain  some Textview and EditText through coding based on server response and showing in the activity .It is working fine.
now I want to show next view / page in the same Activity itself so
so is there any way to change currently showing view .

In other words I can say I want to use one activity as a container and want to draw multiple view in the same activity.

Or i can say Can I call setContentView() multiple time. Or Any other way to do this.

How to implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can call `setContentView` as many times as you want but thats not good programming as it results in untidy code but if you want you can do it.

As far as implementing goes there is nothing big deal when you are done with your first `view` just create new `view` and set the `parent` `layout` of that view in `setContentView`